# Visual Studio 2013 breaking Web Site

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a really weird problem, be interested in some pointers

We have a website that we have coded from Visual Studio 2003 -> Visual Studio 2010. We are now looking at moving to 2013.

The website is in IIS, when I navigate to it using IE it works. When VS2013 is -open-, not running, but has the project open we get a weird effect where the contents of the website gets duplicated by 3, its as if there are 3 iframes on the page, all with a copy of the same web site. 
I close VS2013 and it goes back to normal

So, just to be clear, we don't even have to run the web site from within VS2013, just the project being open is enough to cause the weird effect

We use subversion as as far as I can tell no files have been modified when VS2013 is open

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Browser Link that's doing it! If you switch off Browser Link it works.

The source shows some extra script entries before the final  tag but other than that the whole source is duplicated. 
  We don't need Browser Link and I don't have reflection capabilities on Asp.Net source so as to why that's for some one else to determine, I noticed a few people complaining when I searched on it so it may be something that just gets fixed in a future version